# DRY principle: reference jQuery selector to avoid duplicates

Tags: jquery, dry

Let's suppose I have a function with an object inside

```
function MyFunction(){
    var options = {
        placeholder: $('#select option[value="-1"]'),
        first: $('#select option[value="-1"]').next()
    };
}
```

You see, the jQuery object `$('#select option[value="-1"]')` is duplicated both in `placeholder` and `first` items. This works, but PHPStorm warns me about duplicated jQuery selector

Is there a way I can reference the `placeholder` value in the `first` item? Sort like:

```
placeholder: $('#select option[value="-1"]'),
first: this.placeholder.next()
```

(of course the provided example does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an additional variable:

```
function MyFunction(){
    var options = {};
    options.placeholder = $('#select option[value="-1"]');
    options.first = options.placeholder.next();
}
```

Comment: Creating an external variable is what I'd like to avoid, and this seems the closest answer to my needs. So, I suppose I can't reference *inside* the var options = { ... } directly, and I have to create first an empty object, right?

Comment: Yes, the object must be pre-created and the used property must be defined.

Answer (score 3):

like this?

```
function MyFunction(){
    var el = $('#select option[value="-1"]'),
        options = {
            placeholder: el,
            first: el.next()
        };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply create it as a variable first.

```
function MyFunction(){
    var selected = $('#select option[value="-1"]');
    var options = {
        placeholder: selected,
        first: selected.next()
    };
}
```